# SocketIO JQuery Append Running on Page Load

Tags: jquery, socket.io

Every time I try to use JQuery to amend a form, I get Cannot read property 'undefined' error on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

socket.on('amethod', function (result) {
                for (var item in result) {
                    $(".form").append('input(type="checkbox", name=#{result.result[item].cake})'
                            + '#{result.result[item].cake}');
                }

            });   

        });
```

However replacing it which an alert works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

socket.on('amethod', function (result) {
                for (var item in result) {
                    alert(result.result[item].cake);
                }

            });   

        });
```

I dont know why it is looking at 'result' on page load as socket.on hasnt been called yet, and it will of course be undefined. It doesnt have this issue with an alert. Adding an if(result) catch does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My syntax was wrong

```
     + '#{result.result[item].cake}'
```

Should have just been

```
      + result.result[item].cake
```